# How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, proof-of-ties

How can I prove the immigrant officers that I have significant ties in my home country?

Are there any documents that I need?

Answer (score 8):

Based on your tags my answer will be relevant to a non-immigrant visa for the USA.

You need to prove that you will not stay in the US indefinitely, and that you will return to your home country, hence the demonstration of the 'significant ties'. These may depend on your age too. As a rule of thumb this can include, but is not limited to, the following in your home country:

1. Current job
2. Current education
3. Immediate family members (wife + kids staying behind, elderly parents etc)
4. Active finances i.e. bank account, credit cards, mortgage, loans, lease etc
5. Healthy finances reflected in the above (e.g. you should not have a loan default)
6. Ownership of tangible property (real estate, a house, etc.)
7. Ownership of a business
8. On-going responsibilities (caring for parents, community role, again a job or school, kids' schooling etc)
9. A professional license which needs to be renewed in your home country
10. Insurances (health, life etc)

To summarize, anything that will convince the officer that you will surely return to your home country can be used as proof; and yes that includes your appearance, confidence while you're sitting in front of him/her presenting your case. It all boils down to how well you can present your case and convince the officer that you will return once the visa expires.

Coming to the second part of you questions, documents that you need: any related documentation of the above mentioned points. I will list down examples in the same order below:

1. A letter from your employer's human resources department mentioning your leave.
2. A transcript with all previous semesters' results. A letter from the institution for the reason of travel if it's educational.
3. Marriage/birth certificates. IDs of parents.
4. This is self explanatory, e.g. statements, etc.
5. This would covered in the above documentation.
6. Ownership documentation/registration of your house or leased property.
7. Ownership documentation/tax return of your business.
8. Kids'/spouse's school enrollment documents. Community position documents.
9. Any professional license you have.
10. Insurance policy (provided you have maintained the insurance, not expired or canceled etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. 

I am a recent graduate, however, I am looking for jobs solely in Europe or Asia as I have direct relatives there (parents, grandparents, aunts and sister). 
At the moment I am living in my grandparents house, therefore, does that mean I have to show proof that I am living there? It would be under my grandfather's name. I am being funded by my  parents as they send me money each month and pay for most of my expenses. 

I do have a German and Dutch bank account and have proof that I have studied in the Netherlands (with my degree)

Comment: In Addition, i am 23 years old

Comment: @Ariannakim since you have a German passport you can travel freely in the EU and you won't need to apply for a visa in some asian countries too. You may be entitled to an on arrival visa have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens#/media/File:Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens.png

Answer (score 2):

Having a job in your home country, especially a full-time one.
Owning property there, or having a lease for property (e.g. a rented apartment or home where you live).
Having reasonable to significant amounts of money in banks in your home country.
Having family members back home.

As for documents, it's not usually necessary to have proof of these things, since some of them can be proved using electronic devices (e.g. bank balances) but if you feel there's a significant chance of being refused admission into a country (you haven't given us any details of where you're from nor where you're going), take some bank statements with you, a notarized copy of the title deed from your home, your apartment/home lease, and such with you.

Immigration personnel want to be convinced that you can afford to visit their country using assets you already have, and won't try to immigrate there without proper permission.  Having attachments to another country will convince the officer that you're a genuine tourist.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. I am a recent graduate, however, I am looking for jobs solely in Europe or Asia as I have direct relatives there (parents, grandparents, aunts and sister). At the moment I am living in my grandparents house, therefore, does that mean I have to show proof that I am living there? It would be under my grandfather's name. I am being funded by my parents as they send me money each month and pay for most of my expenses. I do have a German and Dutch bank account and have proof that I have studied in the Netherlands (with my degree)

Comment: In addition, i am 23 years old but since ive finished my studies, this is a break for me before i officially start working.

Comment: If you are traveling to Europe and Asia to look for work, immigration officials may well be concerned about your intentions.  You may want to inquire about whether you qualify for a work permit before you travel.

Comment: The thing is, I have a German passport, therefore I do not have to worry for a work permit if i look for  a job in Europe. Would that be a reasonable answer?

Comment: @Ariannakim If you have a German passport, you have the right of entry into the EU and can work in any EU country, so you would have no need to prove attachment to your home country if you're entering an EU country.

Comment: I also have  a dual passport, since my dad is german and my mom is filipino. Thus, i have a permit to work in the philippines as well. Is it safe to say i have a dual citizenship?

Comment: @Ariannakim If you have two passports from two different countries, you are indeed a dual citizen.  Passports are only issued to citizens.