# Schengen business visa for a recent graduate

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, conferences

I am an Indian passport holder and have very recently graduated from university (about 3 weeks ago). My thesis work has been accepted as a research paper at a top conference in Germany. I plan to attend the conference (in September) to present my work. Consequently, I am applying for the Schengen business visa.

I have already accepted a job from a well-known company in the US and will be joining them in November in the US or Canada. Meanwhile, I am interning at a startup in India. I am facing a dilemma regarding the documents I must submit to demonstrate my ties to my home country. I am planning to submit the following:

1. Offer letter from the company based in the US.
2. Letter from the startup mentioning that I am currently employed (as an intern).
3. Leave letter from the startup for the period of stay.

Are these documents sufficient to demonstrate my intent to return after the conference? Also, my father is funding my trip. Will this be a problem? Any help would be much appreciated, as I have already registered for the conference, booked flights and hotels.

Edit:
Just wanted to update. I got my visa!

Comment: Do you already have your US/Canada work visa?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The company applied for an H-1B, but I was not picked in the lottery. They are now looking for alternatives in Canada. Does this make it look even worse? :(

Comment: The US offer letter doesn’t demonstrate ties to home, and without the visa it’s a weaker reason to leave Schengen than it would have been with the visa. Needing a sponsor for the trip can also count against an applicant. But as Henrik says, no-one can predict the outcome.

Comment: The leave letter from the startup mentions that I will resuming duties after the trip. I am hoping it will make my case a little better. Also, would it be appropriate to enclose the H1-B petition documents although it was later not selected in the 
lottery?

Comment: [This question on how to document home ties](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country) might be helpful.

Comment: Just wanted to update. I got my visa!

Answer (score 1):

I would be satisfied with those documents as demontrating intention to leave ( would be satisfied with the offer from the US company and some proof you've accepted it), but I'm not the one who has to evaluate your application, neither is anyone else here (I guess), so we can't guarantee you that you will get any particular result. But go ahead and apply.

Comment: "We can't answer your question" is a reason to close. It's not really an answer.