# After being refused entry, how long should I wait to apply for a US B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens, denial-of-entry

I'm from the UK and I'm 27 years of age. My girlfriend lives in Chicago in the USA. I've been with her for 3 years I have went to see her last year July 2018, staying for 3 months and entering on an ESTA.

Then, I tried going back in December on the ESTA, and was refused entry at the border, sent home, and my ESTA was cancelled.

Now, I need a visa to go see her. I'm worried because I'm scared I might get denied. I don't work in the UK, haven't for few weeks; I do live in a flat but I only just moved in the beginning of February.

I don't know if I should apply for a visa or is it to soon and should I wait a month or two because I only just got a flat? What should I do?

Added from what had been posted as an answer:

I just received that's I understand why I got sent back and that's it and I sighed it I sighed it cause they said if I didn't I could get banned from the USA all together they said we sending you back so you can never come back on an ESTA again; you will need a visa if you want to come to the USA and I only stayed 89 days last time I was there ....

I lost my job cause it was agency work

Also I have could start new job for a agency Monday so I was thinking do two months working and that will be 3 months I been in my flat then apply for the visa would that be a good idea

Also my girlfriend has a very good job and she said she could help pay for it; she earns 65 or 70k a year.

And I was thinking going for 2 to 3 weeks ...

Comment: What paperwork did you receive when you were refused entry to the US?

Comment: @J.roberts14 Not having a job in the UK is arguably a much bigger hurdle to getting a visa than having only just moved into your flat. You need to be able to overcome the assumption of immigrant intent by demonstrating you have strong ties to the UK https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Comment: What was the cause of you not working in the UK for a few weeks?

Comment: "staying for 3 months and entering on an ESTA": three months is a little imprecise, but it could be longer than 90 days, the period of admission for visa waiver program visitors.  Did you in fact leave on or before the departure date you had been given?  If not, that would explain the refusal of entry, and an honest mistake of a day or two should not be too hard to overcome in a subsequent visa application (if indeed it was an honest mistake).

Comment: Whatever you do, I strongly recommend that you only plan a short visit of a couple of weeks next time. If you keep trying to make long visits to your girlfriend, it looks _a lot_ like you're trying to live in the US.

Comment: Don’t attempt going back for at least a year while improving your profile and stability.

Answer (score 7):

The situation you are describing - relationship with a US resident, long visit followed by recent denial of entry, no current job / agency work in the UK, rented accommodation - unfortunately makes it pretty likely that you will not get a visa to visit the US any time soon. If your girlfriend can afford the trip, she can come visit you instead.