# I won a contest. The company is sponsoring my trip. What documents do I require for a UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, india

I live in Mumbai, India. 
The trip is for 2 Nights. The company would be sponsoring me with:

- Return Air tickets
- Hotel Accommodation(Breakfast included)
- Airport transfer
- Match tickets

What all documents do I need for UK Visa with me as well as from the company sponsoring me?
I am pursuing my Master's course from India. I am currently not employed.

Answer (score 3):

Guidance on the documents you’ll need is stated here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

You’ll need to provide proof of the sponsorship, your bank statements [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and evidence to demonstrate your ties to India [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Note that even with a sponsor the onus is still on you to demonstrate that you qualify. IMHO, a 2 night trip as a premise for your visit doesn’t sound like a particularly credible reason so you’ll need to ensure your application is watertight. UKVI will want to verify that your competition win is bona fide.

Comment: The company will be providing me with sponsorship document and a proof that I've won the contest. Since the prize is "tickets to an EPL match", therefore might hold credibility. Also, the company itself is renowned and is a sponsor to that UK based team. So my trip is of officially 2 nights.

Answer (score 2):

I'd apply without mentioning a "sponsor" to make the application stronger but rather state that "somebody else would be paying for a part of your trip" (as far as I remember there's a question to this effect in the application for a visitor visa) and detailing your win in the text field.

As for the supporting documents, I'd enclose the proof of your win and **focus on proving your ties to your country**, e.g. a confirmation from your university, your family situation, stuff you own...

Such a short stay would probably be inexpensive, but a bank statement with some positive balance (reasonable for the area you'll be staying in) and a sensible spending history can be helpful too and also prove your ties to your country.