# Applying for a US travel visa after denial

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, uk-residents, polish-citizens

Last August I went to the US embassy in London, UK and tried to get a travel visa to the USA, and it was denied due to insufficient ties to the UK. I'm a Polish citizen living in the UK for almost six years, I moved here with my mother and sister, and we decided to stay here. I'm also a student, currently doing HND (Higher National Diploma) which is somehow an equivalent to the 2nd year of uni, but cheaper.

During the interview, I lied about not having a job as I have thought that it would make my situation worse (I'm a software developer, and all my clients come from the US). I was asked where I live, I said with parents and what my sister and parents are doing (jobs, etc.).

Now I'm thinking about trying again but this time telling the truth about my job, but probably this won't make a difference. Also, I've heard that it's statistically much harder to get the travel visa in London than for example Krakow or Warsaw in Poland. Can I apply for the visa in my home country, does it make any sense to do it this way?

Do I have any chance of getting it?

Answer (score 3):

Whether you apply in London or Poland, your main problem remains: you lied on your previous application.

If the visa processing officers find out that you lied then your credibility is wrecked, your chances of getting a visa are negligible, and you could find yourself banned for a long time.

If you change your story about your job you will have to come up with a watertight explanation for the change in circumstances. This might be difficult after just six months.

I am **not** advocating that you lie again. Rather, if you leave another application until a couple of years have passed it's easier to account for having a good income that will draw you back to the UK.

If you **must** visit the USA it might pay to get advice from a competent immigration lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Looks like I don't have any other option than wait a bit.

Comment: @Di96 Meantime you should work on improving your ties to the UK. Living with non-dependent family and having a job that can be done from anywhere with all your clients in the US doesn’t exactly make a strong case to demonstrate non-immigrant intent. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country