# Help with UK visa from Oman

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

We are hoping my boyfriend can travel from Oman to the UK on a standard visitor visa. It'd be for around 2 weeks, his father would be financing it, he is studying in Oman but is originally from Egypt. I was hoping I could receive some advice as I've been reading here about visa refusals. Of course we don't want to lie and not mention that he is visiting his girlfriend, but how can he convince immigration that his intent is not to stay here? I read that him being in education should help, but is there any other documentation or evidence he can provide as proof? Also, regarding finances, would 6 months of bank statements be enough proof of funds or would he need to get translated payslips/proof of employment (hoping to avoid this as it would take a while).

If there's any other advice you have on how to get a visa accepted, or links to useful information, we would be very grateful. We're quite young so not used to such serious and intense documents, and I really don't want to mess up! Thank you.

Comment: Reading the guidance should help https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/793361/Visit-guidance-v8.0ext.pdf Also this related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country and this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: There’s nothing special about his case. Spending an hour a day for a week or so reading highly rated questions on UK visas from here will answer any questions you have and more and guide you to avoid elementary mistakes and avoid tripping over hidden requirements. Also it is important he take the initiative doing the research himself also, since he will be the one applying.

Comment: _We're quite young so not used to such serious and intense documents_  

Comment: @user56513 hi! i'm glad to hear there's nothing special, hopefully that'll work in our favour. I've sent him the links, but the issue we're really struggling with is do we mention that I'm his girlfriend or not? I've read lots and lots of things suggesting not to, saying that there may be background checks or refusal based on it. But if we want to apply for a fiance visa later on it might work against us. Any advice would be appreciated!