# Canadian visitors visa

Tags: visas, canada, applications

My mom wants to bring her mom and niece to canada for 3 months. Her mom came to canada many years ago however her niece has never traveled anywhere (she's 19). When we applied for the visa my mom’s niece got denied because they're not sure if she will return to their home country after the trip is over although we can 100% guarantee that both will leave when the trip is over. How can we prove this to the immigration officer because we know that you have to show strong ties to your home country but we're not sure what strong ties a 19 year old can have given her age.

please reply with any advice for getting visa approved when we reapply

Comment: attending school? job? married? owning house?

Comment: What reason(s) does she have that would compel her to go back apart from ‘that’s where I live’? Possible duplicate of [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: "we can 100% guarantee that both will leave when the trip is over" 1. No you can't: they're independent human beings who can do as they please. 2. Everybody says that, anyway.

Comment: We know that they will leave canada because their entire family is back home and they dont have enough money to permanently live here in canada since we will be paying for everything for them and they will be living at my house

Comment: @Johnny Please read the link cited by Traveller and the reference at the top of the page. As David Richerby correctly observes: "Everyone says that." A successful visa application will describe the applicant's circumstances in enough detail to convince Canadian Immigration that the visitor will depart on time. Here, "Entire family" is imprecise, and three months looks like a very long a trip that resembles moving to Canada to live there...particularly odd for someone who can't afford the trip without assistance.

Comment: @Johnny Unfortunately having family in Canada increases the immigration risk profile of a young person with no previous travel history and no economic ties to their country of residence. There’s a great graphic here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy showing how this might work (it is for a Schengen application but the principle is universal). There’s little point reapplying unless her circumstances have changed