# B2 Visa refusal

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I am an international student from India, on a student Visa in Australia, currently studying in an Australian university in Melbourne. I had applied for a b2 Visa. And I got rejected under the grounds that I didnt demonstrate strong ties. 
I was planning on visiting my friend during my semester end break. 
The officer asked me how my studies were funded. I said from an education loan back in India. Then he asked me the purpose of my visit and the duration to which I replied tentatively a month and half. And finally asked me if I was single. To which I replied yes. 
And the rejection, I asked for the reason to which he replied I havent stayed in Australia long enough (I have been here 5 months) to prove that I will be able to come back. 
Can anyone help me figure out what exactly might have gone wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what more there is to say. The visa officer wasn't sufficiently convinced that you'd leave the US at the end of your visit. Since you've only just started your degree, the implicit argument of "Look how much of my life I would have wasted if I don't go back and finish my degree" isn't very strong. There are plenty of questions on this site about proving ties to your home country/country of residence. I'm not sure if any are specifically about the USA but the same general principles should apply.

Comment: Which of the several reasons the officer gave you is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't qualify for the visa because the consular officer decided that you did not overcome the required presumption under U.S. law  that every visitor visa applicant is an intending immigrant until they demonstrate otherwise.

Applicants for visitor visas must overcome this presumption by demonstrating:

• That the purpose of their trip is to enter the United States temporarily for business or pleasure;

• That they plan to remain for a specific, limited period;

• Evidence of funds to cover expenses in the United States;

• That they have a residence outside the United States as well as other binding ties that will ensure their departure from the United States at the end of the visit.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/PDF-other/VisaFlyer_B1B2_March_2015.pdf

In your case, unfortunately you fit the profile of a typical high immigration risk application. You’re single and have already left behind your home country, you’ve only recently started your studies so could potentially easily abandon them, and you’re funding your studies from borrowed resources. [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So when do you think I should apply? Or how is it that I can make my case strong? Since my USA plans are foiled, I will be flying back to India. My friend suggested to apply from India for the Visa again. In October that is. Do you think it's a wise decision or should I completely drop the plan of applying now?

Comment: IMHO you’ll get another refusal unless your circumstances change significantly eg a job, savings.

Comment: But the thing is, I still have a year left of my degree to complete for which I will have to return to Melbourne. Isnt that reason enough? The significant change will be I completed my first year as opposed to just a semester when I gave the interview. And another year left to go. As I graduate in November 2020