# Uk Visit Visa Rejected, Should i reapply?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, conferences

I'm a student from Pakistan I was willing to attend GopherCon UK 2019 I had purchased a ticket. I had provided all of the required documents. My visa was refused due to a lack of financial evidence. I had Provided **the following Documents**:

- ID ( Passport ID Card) Cover Letter. Bonafide Letter from University.
  Invitation letter from the Conference. Paid Ticket of the conference
  Past educational Proofs Booking of Return Flight
- Mother's Documents include Declaration Letter, Bank Certificate,
  Proof of current property ownership, Proof of Relation, Husband's
  Death Certificate, Insurance Letter
- Sponsor(UK), Invitation Letter, Passport, Bank Statements, PayRols,
  p60, Accommodation Proof, PaySlips of Last 6 Months

and a few other documents to support my case.

[image: Rejection Letter]

Comment: Do you or your mother have any source of income? Or do you rely solely on that savings account? If so, unless there's really lot of money in there, you would look like a good candidate to try to emigrate to find a job that pays better than in would in your home country...

Comment: @jcaron Yes we have leased one portion on our home which is owned by my mother i had attached all the documents, lease agreements, property taxes tenat registerations for that. The amount invested/saved and the rent generates more than enough income for me and my mother to live by and save for my career and education.i sometimes do freelancing which is extremely hard to proof due to inconcictency. Thats why i didnt even bothered mentioning that.

Comment: Well that rent surely goes into an account somewhere? Did you provide the statements for that account?

Comment: Please don't use picture images, if you can easily copy paste the text, please do so to make it easier for search and accessibility purposes.

Comment: @jcaron they are handed in cash which is spent for our daily expences ( for that month)

Comment: @JJJ this looks like a scan of the refusal letter, which is delivered on paper AFAIK.

Comment: @FaqahatFareed I’m afraid that probably doesn’t help your case much. ECOs like to see money coming into a bank account on a regular basis, along with justification of where that money came from. Anything else is just words for them.

Comment: @jcaron i recieved the letter in e-mail. The question is if i reapply by providing the source and origin of the funds in account?

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here: the origin of the money you mother is sponsoring you with; and the suspicion that you will go underground once you arrive, overstay, and work illegally.

The first of these is a documentary issue. If you have documents relating to the sale and reasonably regular bank statements since showing that the money has remained in your family then that should suffice.

The second problem is more difficult to resolve. Th immigration officer believes it likely that you will not return to Pakistan. You need to show strong ties to your home country that will make it likely that you will. The IO is looking for a regular responsible job, property ownership, and dependent relatives, amongst other things. As a student you are unlikely to have any of these.

I can't tell you whether you should re-apply, but unless you can address these issues effectively you are likely to be refused again. Bear in mind that multiple refusals can reflect badly on an applicant - it might look like you are desperate.

Good luck!

Comment: As for the statement i have mentioned reasons why i can not provide a regular statement. But i am able to provide a proof of origin of the funds. As for second part in my covering letter i have mentioned that i am care taker of my single mother (since im the only child). Also a proof of university program which im half way through of 4 year engineering program. I dont know what more proofs i can provide for my return

Comment: If you reapply, you should also consider explaining a) is the premise of your visit reasonable for someone in your position? Why do you want to attend this event? For example, are you connected with it in your home country? Will it assist your studies? If so, how? And b) is the total amount you are proposing to spend proportionate to your/your sponsors’ circumstances?  And c) why do you have what appears to be 2 financial sponsors? This question discusses ties to home https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Comment: In my application i mentioned why im visiting the event how its related to my studies and i also included 7 certificates of participations on similar events in current country. I also mentioned the amount i was willing to spend and which sponsor is willing to help with how much and in which parts of my journey. As for personal / family documents. I do have a driving licence that needs to be renewed next year. I have a on going university program (which i already proved). I also had attached a proof of insurance which was tied to my mother and me.

Comment: @FaqahatFareed I think you'll find it difficult to claim that the person sponsoring you is also a dependent relative.

Comment: @ReddHerring im realizing that too, however it shouldnt be this complicated since my mother is aged now and our whole family resides on 2 persons me and my mother. She is financially independent (im not) but she still needs me for social ,  care taking and other personal reasons which i think is pretty understandable given the circumstances but as you said its hard to prove.