# Australian Tourist Visa (600) denied because of no proof of ties

Tags: visa-refusals, australia, tourist-visas, filipino-citizens, proof-of-ties

I just want to ask. I am a permanent resident in Australia. I applied for a tourist visa for my sister and my niece (sister's daughter) but they got denied. Reason was they think my sister might not comeback to the Philippines. My sister is unemployed but it's her choice because she is a full time mother. Her husband is working in Dubai. We provided  evidences including Marriage certificate, bank statement, car registration named after my sister, and my sisters husband working visa but I guess it's not enough. I planned to appeal but after learning that the price is 1,700 aud . I think the best option is to re apply. The planned vacation in October 2019 is now cancelled. MY sisters situation will not change if she re apply but I advice them if they want to re apply, they should wait for her husband to come along with them in Australia.
MY brother in law will apply for all them since he is the bread winner.

Questions how long can they re apply for the tourist visa and since my sister's situation will not change like she will not find a work just to get a tourist visa will she ever have the chance to get approve?

Also, according to the refusal letter my sister does not have any ties in the Philippines for her to stay. She has 2 kids and only one of them will go with her since the other one is in college. She also has a land property under her name but I did not include and attached it when I applied for them because there is a typo error in the Tax Declaration of the land.

---

Thank you for responding. Most likely my sister situation will not change. The only thing will change is that my brother in law (her husband) will travel with them and will apply for all of them. e is the bread winner Hope that will be enough. and the land property of both of them since they are married and its conjugal property,they will declare.

I know its my mistake not including my sisters land tax declaration. It's actually not a typo sorry for using that word, its just it stated in the land tax declaration that my sister's name appears correct but her husband is totally incorrect because it is a name of a different person which I thought will make things worst if I attach it.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Answer (score 4):

It was a mistake to not include the evidence of land ownership. A typo isn't likely to matter much or at all, but it does show evidence of intention to leave Australia. This should be included.

A child in college is not necessarily a sufficient family tie to show intention to leave, but a minor child would be. Since that child would have been traveling to Australia with her, there's no intention to leave demonstrated.

There's no required waiting period before reapplying, unless the refusal letter specifically mentions one. The important part of reapplying is that the new application must show significant changes in personal circumstances, or it will likely be refused again.

Comment: my sisters situation will not change but her husband will apply a tourist visa for all of them and together they will travel. do you reckon it will be the best and she will have a chance?

Comment: @Dench It's impossible to say with certainty if the new application will be successful, but it seems more likely than the previous one.

Comment: While in general 'the new application must show significant changes in personal circumstances' is good advice, there is anecdotal evidence (for Australia at least) that better evidence/presentation does help.