# Can I bring my poor neighbor to the UK as a visitor?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-ties, visa-sponsors

I am from India, and I grew up in childhood with a poor neighbour of mine, of the age of my parents. They took very good care of me, our economic disparity notwithstanding.

Now I am working in the UK on a tier-2 visa in a cushy job, and would like to bring them (a man and a woman) to the UK on a visitor visa. I can fully sponsor them and provide my bank statements and a written invite. However, this alone will not be enough I think. They need to convince the visa officer that they will return to India after the trip.

They do not have any assets or fixed deposits, nor any kids. Under such circumstances, is there any possibility to bring them over? Will a return flight ticket be a proof (I think not).

Comment: This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country relates to the US but is also relevant to the UK. If they can’t tick any of the boxes at all (no job, no family, no assets/savings etc) the chances of getting a visa are pretty low.

Comment: Without knowing UK visa policies in the least, young people are a greater risk for staying and working. Why would an elderly couple with no money try to immigrate? Good luck.

Comment: @Aaron Brick Because they already have someone in the UK who could support them to overstay, without the need to work? Because they hope to get free medical treatment? Or even claim asylum? Not saying these reasons apply in this case, just providing examples of how an ECO might think.

Comment: You don’t gain anything from this act. They don’t gain anything either. For the amount of money involved you can probably do something for them to improve their life where they are. Or maybe pay off some of their pending bills or buy them something that improves their life.  Chances or approval for a visa in this case would be negligible.

Comment: @HankyPanky I agree that the chances of approval are low but the rest of the comment just reads like knowing better what's good for OP and their neighbours.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try for a visa does it?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify queries. Putting on hold for now