# UK visit visa for parents and employment letters from independent children

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

Need an advice for UK visit visa. As my parents applying for visa and only mum is financialy dependant on my dad. I have 2 brothers both are working and we havent shown them in dependants and they will be only counted in family ties back home. Should I attach their employment letters? Or is it just extra burden by giving irrelevant documents.

Comment: I don’t see how your brothers’ employment letters are relevant to your parents’ applications if they’re not contributing financially to the trip and/or your parents are not dependent on them. See also this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Comment: @Traveller There's some relevance, as family (the brothers) at home are a "tie" to the home country, and therefore supports the applicants' assertion that they'll leave the UK after the trip and return to their home country.

Comment: Thank you Traveller and David. That was helpful

Comment: @David I don’t disagree, the point I was trying to make is that employment letters don’t necessarily prove a family tie. An ECO might wonder how strong a ‘tie’ independent, employed, adult children in home country are, compared with ties to an adult child in similar circumstances in the UK.

Comment: @Traveller I certainly agree. While the parents may have strong relationships with the stay-at-home brothers, demonstrating it may well consume more of the ECO's attention and time resources than its resulting weight would justify.

Comment: Parents have their own running business and properties for which they will have to return. I was just wondering if the children employment can increase the  household income and shows what my father is earning belongs to him and my mother. In cover letter i will write both sons are working but not sure if I have to attach a letter to prove it. As in cover you can write anything which is not true