# Questions at the US Port of Entry

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I would be traveling to the US on an H1B for the first time next month. My fiancee and I traveled together on B1/B2 a few months back. She has a 10 year valid B1/B2 visa. Therefore we are planning to travel together this time. We are not planning on getting married any time soon. Her plan would be to spend some time and come back in a few months time.

I have read in many forums about the question on "intent to immigrate" at the port of entry. Will it be a problem for us to enter, if she is viewed as planning to stay with me forever. She would be definitely returning back to India. 
But I am scared: in case the officer is not convinced, will it lead to problems? 
Or am I over thinking the situation?

Please share your suggestions and experiences.

Thanks

Comment: How long is ‘a few months’? What ties to India will she be able to prove?

Comment: At this point, we are thinking of about 4 months. She has her family to look after, her old parents back home. She is the one who always takes care of them.

Comment: How long was the previous trip? Have her circumstances changed significantly since the visa was approved and/or her previous visit? Does this answer your question? [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: In the previous trip, both of us went for a period of 7 days. During that time, my current employer had invited (and sponsered) both of us for small work related discussion. Now I have got the job offer and have got my h1b visa. However, she is on B1/B2, which is still valid.

Comment: Some questions the immigration officer might think of:  If she's taking care of her parents, how will they manage without her for four months?  Does she have a job in India?  If so, how will she remain away from it for four months?  How long are you planning to stay in the US?  How will you and your fiancée cope with being separated for that length of time minus four months?

Comment: @Anonymous_1 Your question is vague on the intended trip length. Just to check - will your fiancée have a booked return ticket? It’s most definitely a bad idea to arrive without one.

Comment: @Traveller a definite plan to return is probably more important than the actual ticket.  A ticket will of course go a long way toward helping to establish that the plan to return is definite, though, and the absence of the ticket will probably make it difficult to establish that.  Other factors can also play an important role, though, and they should not be overlooked.