# Help with rejection for Canadian visa paragraph 179(b) of the IRPR, Possible resolution

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens, visa-rejections

How is it possible to resolve something like this

"**I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your stay as a temporary resident, as stipulated in paragraph 179(b) of the IRPR, based on the purpose of your visit** "

This is the line sent to me as regards my visa refusal by IRCC

Earlier:

- I did not have the Itinerary included
- I did not have a letter of invitation added (As canada does not basically need it), I just got my hotel reservation confirmation and added to my application
- I added a proof of funds (From my fathers company as well as the one from my company I work with)
- I included an affidavit detailing that I also partake in running my fathers 
  business etc.

**Possible Resolution**

- I requested a letter of invitation from a friend who invited me for a personal visit to his family in Canada
- I Included an Itinerary detailing a 13 day visit from Lagos Nigeria, to Calgary, then on to Grand Prairie, from there       back to Calgary and back to Lagos Nigeria
- I included the two hotel reservations I need as stated in my itinerary.
- I included a cover Letter, detailing the proof of funds and other information about my application
- I included an affidavit detailing that I also partake in running my fathers 
  business etc and my office salaries (proof of fund etc).

Please advise, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a history of travel, particularly to any of the equivalent jurisdictions such as Schengen, Australia, UK? What ties to home can you demonstrate other than your job https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country?

Comment: That is the only thing I do not have at this particular time. I detailed it in my application that i do not have this.

Comment: For ties to home other than my job, I have landed properties too given to me by my parents. And i am in civil union with someone and we plan on getting married anytime soon. I did not detail the part of the Properties in a sworn affidavit. is that something i did not catch?

Comment: Yes, you should disclose real property that you own in your name, because this makes your application stronger. People who own land are considered less likely to overstay their visas and more likely to be approved.