# If someone is refused visa in any one of the “Five Eyes” countries, does this affect his subsequent visa applications in other “Five Eyes” countries?

Tags: usa, uk, canada, australia, student-visas

Suppose, someone is refused a study visa from Canada thrice. Reasons include:

1. lack of fund
2. lack of travel history
3. will not return

I can improve #1 by obtaining a scholarship. I can improve #2 by traveling.

But, how can I improve #3?

Is it highly likely that he would be refused a visa in subsequent applications in other Five Eyes members?

Comment: If your situation (ie. the case you present with your documentation) does not improve, then you're likely to be denied for those same reasons. If your case improves and you are honest on the application, then maybe. We can't tell you 100%.

Comment: #3 probably refers to lack of ties to home country. Look at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country for specific examples. Hope that helps

Comment: @ozzy, if someone can obtain a Ph.D. finance, can he still be considered negative in #3?

Comment: Yes, it can be considered a negative under #3. The idea of a visa is that the visa-holder _will return to their home country_ after the visa term. Doesn't matter what you've accomplished during the visa term: the ECO must be satisfied that after that term, the applicant will return to the home country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I'm not an expert myself, but I had a roommate from El Salvador, living in Taiwan, he applied for an Australian tourist visa to go see his sister, and it was denied. One year later he applied for a USA tourist visa and he got it. What changed? Well, when he applied for the Australian one he was still a student when he applied for the USA he had already landed a job in Taiwan.

Since these 5 countries share visa information among them, I would say yes, if you get a visa denied then it will affect subsequent applications in other of the 5 countries, but if you improve your profile by having a good job, savings, and travel history, then you can change the outcome of your application.

Answer (score 4):

The "Five Eyes" all exchange information about visa applications. so...

**Yes, your refusal of a Canadian visa may affect your applications to other countries.**

That does not mean you will necessarily be refused a visa by those countries but there will be an effect. A triple-refusal is worse than a single refusal, because it indicates a 'get a visa at all costs" attitude which is itself suspicious.

All those countries require you to disclose information about refused visa applications from other countries, so you can be certain that they will know about your refusals. You need to tell them about the refusals when they ask because **lying on a visa application is going to get you not just a refusal but a ban.** Don't even think about failing to disclose the refusals.

After a triple refusal you are probably best off waiting a while before any future application. The ways to deal with the specific points are:

1. Make sure you have sufficient money of your own, or from other legitimate sources (such as a scholarship) to cover your expenses. Do not accept loans or other temporary funding in order to boost your finances.
2. Establish a record of visits to other countries, even as a tourist/visitor.
3. Make for yourself ties to your homeland that will make it necessary for you to return.

Comment: *Make for yourself ties to your homeland that will make it necessary for you to return.* --- this is a gray area. I have a well-established relationship with my family. They know that. So, why did they say I can't return home, is not obvious to me.

Comment: Yes, it's a grey area. It's not about how well you get on with your family, it's about how likely you are to return. You might love your family very much but still decide to stay in Canada after your visa runs out. Things that reduce that would include: a wife or children in your home country; a job waiting for you when you return; owning a house.

Comment: Does this affect application to other Anglophonic countries like Ireland and South Africa also?

Comment: To a lesser extent. Everything is going to affect everything at least a bit.

Comment: I only have wife and child, no job and property is mortgaged. I am searching for a PhD scholarship, and is highly likely to get an offer very shortly. After your answer and one comment from "DavidSupportsMonica" I am in two minds. Should I abandon my plan altogether?

Comment: I can't answer that. But if your circumstances haven't changed since your three refusals, acceptance is not very likely.