# Do i need to show my Canadian study visa refusal to the UK embassy for study visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, applications, study

I got a refusal from Canadian embassy, there is no stamp on my passport,  do I need to show my Canadian study visa refusal to the UK embassy for study visa?

My agent,however, recommends me not to show the refusal.

Comment: I think your agent is wrong, at least wait for answers here.

Comment: As allready commented, you agent is giving you bad advice. You will be asked about any refusals, which you should always answer honestly. Supplying the Canadian refusal letter will show your good intentions to be forthright in your application.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156800/if-someone-is-refused-visa-in-any-one-of-the-five-eyes-countries-does-this-af Your agent is giving very bad advice. Remember that a) you don’t need to use an agent to apply for a visa; b) they get their fee regardless of whether your application succeeds or not; c) they won’t be the one stuck with a 10 year ban for deception

Comment: Whenever I hear of visa **agents** from developing countries, the picture that comes to mind is unethical+sometimes ignorant+money hungry opportunists and I am hardly ever wrong. I knew many of such types back in the day.

Answer (score 9):

You should disclose any relevant information, including any prior refusals.  Your Canadian refusal may make it more difficult to get a UK visa, but consider the alternative.

Canada and the UK share immigration data under the Five Eyes treaty. You should assume that the UK already knows you have been refused. If you fail to disclose this fact then the UK may consider this to be deception and impose a ten year ban.

Answer (score 0):

You should truthfully answer the questions presented to you in the visa application. You are not required to volunteer information which is not asked for. Thus, if Canada asks if you've ever been refused a visa, you must disclose it.

If you do not disclose it, and Canada already knows about the refusal (a very likely situation, for the Five Eyes reason described in the other answer), you will be denied for deception, and possibly banned as well.

Your agent is giving you bad advice.