# How to get a leave letter for unemployed for UK visa?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-of-ties

I am applying for UK visa, I have all the requirements needed like Sponsor letter, my bank statements as well as bank statements and payslips of my sponsor. His proof of ownership for the place where I will stay during my visit, ITR, and any other documents except "Leave letter", cause I am redundant at my work since june 15, 2020.

I have a previous UK visa before and been to the UK twice but the visa already expired. Now I am applying again for 6 months visit visa.
How possible that I can get the visa without "leave letter". What I'm supposed to do? Can I ask my sponsor as well for "leave letter"? What other options to get "Leave letter"?

Comment: What do you intend to do in the UK, and how will you pay your living expenses while there?

Answer (score 14):

The purpose of a ‘leave letter’ is to help demonstrate ties to your home country and a compelling reason to leave the UK at the end of your visit. The options you have if you no longer have employment to return to include a) defer your trip until you have a new job and can get a leave letter, or a contract showing a confirmed start date; or b) prove other ties eg dependent family. This question might be helpful with the latter [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Answer (score 13):

If you are not working then it doesn't make any sense to have a "leave letter". There is nobody to give you one. It is not necessary. Of course you have very little chance of getting a visa while unemployed.

Comment: Yes, it is. Good luck getting a visitors' visa here if you don't have a job to go back to. That is exactly why they ask for such a letter, and this is exactly why the OP isn't going to get the visa.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Obviously they aren't likely to get the visa while unemployed. That still doesn't change the fact that you can't get a letter from a job you don't have.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. The answer's better now as before it seemed like you were saying that was all gravy. "It is not necessary" is a weird thing to say in this context.

Comment: *"you have very little chance of getting a visa while unemployed"* - unless you are independently wealthy and can show that you have enough passive income to not become reliant on working illegally in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

Immigration uses a process where they *assume that you intend to permanently immigrate to the UK, seek employ or go on the dole*... and then, allow you to present data that proves otherwise.

That’s why proof of ties to your home country is so important.  For instance suppose you are running a serious political campaign for a seat in your state legislature.  That’s an excellent “tie” because nobody does that and emigrates.

Likewise it helps if you are on a career track with a job, own a home, have a family, have elder-care duties, and other social obligations back home.

**A sponsor does more harm than good**.  When the keystone of your application is a “sponsor letter”, *it means you don’t have anything better to lead with*, which says the application is *very* weak.  Further, depending on the context, a “sponsor letter” can suggest illegal activity, such as “working under the table” for the sponsor or friend.

If you are attempting to use a “visitor visa”, which is largely for tourism, your case is *particularly* weak since COVID-19 is taking all the fun out of tourism.